# What is the best way to document and archive my past games?

Tags: learning, beginner, database

I am looking for more sophisticated solutions for documenting, archiving and analysing my past games. Right now I have a folder filled with PGN files. What systems have proved to work well?

Comment: I suggest to store all your games in a single pgn, that should make it much less messy in the file system, plus you can then actually search through your games.

Comment: Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Actually, add far as i know you can just concatenate the files. If you are on Mac/Linux,  this can be done easily with the cat tool. I am sure there is an easy way on Windows as well. Maybe you can tell what system you're on,  then i can give some details.

Comment: I'm using both Linux and OS X.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you to use a game database software, as [Scid](http://scid.sourceforge.net/), [Scid vs PC](http://scidvspc.sourceforge.net/), [ChessX](https://sourceforge.net/projects/chessx/), [ChessDB](http://chessdb.sourceforge.net/), [Scid on the Go](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.scid.android&hl=en) (Android), etc.

I use Scid for all of that (documenting, archiving and analysing) and it works really well.

Comment: I've downloaded Scid vs Mac and ChessX for trying them out.